# The app wasn't found in the list of installed apps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I was trying to open the Notifications Settings screen on a button click in my app but I get an error toast message saying

> The app wasn't found in the list of installed apps

I was following the Android training [documents](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#UpdateChannel) and double checked my package name but I'm not sure why I can't get it to work.

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS).apply {
                    putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, "com.xyz.abc")
                    putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, "com.xyz.abc.SomeUniqueString")
                }
                startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your package name programatically, no need to write packagename hardcoded. Get like this:

```
String packageName=getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
```

You can also check this app is installed or not:

```
 List<PackageInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(PackageInfo packageInfo:apps){
    if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(packageName)){
//app is installed. do whatever you want
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I was hardcoding it but yeah it worked when I used the function to get the package name.

Answer (score 0):

for expo use:

```
startActivityAsync(ActivityAction.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS, {
        extra: {
          'android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE':
            Constants?.manifest?.android?.package,
          app_package: Constants?.manifest?.android?.package,
        },
      })
```